# c++ Inheritance and shared pointers

Tags: c++, inheritance, shared-ptr

Here is the situation. Let's say we have a virtual base class (e.g. `ShapeJuggler`) which contains a method that takes a shared pointer to a virtual base class object (e.g. `Shape`) as argument. Let's jump into the following pseudo-code to understand:

```
class Shape {
}
class ShapeJuggler {
    virtual void juggle(shared_ptr<Shape>) = 0;
}
// Now deriving a class from it
class Square : public Shape {
}
class SquareJuggler : public ShapeJuggler {
public:
    void juggle(shared_ptr<Shape>) {
         // Want to do something specific with a 'Square'
         // Or transform the 'shared_ptr<Shape>' into a 'shared_ptr<Square>'
    }
}
// Calling the juggle method
void main(void) {
    shared_ptr<Square> square_ptr = (shared_ptr<Square>) new Square();
    SquareJuggler squareJuggler;
    squareJuggler.juggle(square_ptr); // how to access 'Square'-specific members?
}
```

make_shared or dynamic/static_cast don't seem to do the job.
Is it at all possible? Any ideas, suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: `main()` should return `int`, not `void`.

Comment: "_we have a virtual base class_" you forgot the **virtual** keyword in your example (or "pseudo-code")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is where [`std::dynamic_pointer_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast) (or one of its friends) comes into play.
It's just like `dynamic_cast`, but for `std::shared_ptr`s.

In your case (assuming the `Shape` class is polymorphic so `dynamic_cast` works):

```
void juggle(shared_ptr<Shape> shape) {
    auto const sq = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Square>(shape);
    assert(sq);

    sq->squareSpecificStuff();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the *multiple dispatch* problem. Their are many solution to this problem, the cleanest might be using the *visitor pattern*, but if you just have one function that need *multiple dispatch* you could avoid using a visitor:

```
class SquareJuggler;
class TriangleJuggler;
//.... others concrete jugglers.

class Shape {
    //The default behaviour for any juggler and any shape
    virtual void juggle_by(Juggler& t) {
       //default code for any shape an juggle
    }
    // list each juggler for which you may
    // implement a specific behavior
    virtual void juggle_by(SquareJuggler& t) {
      //provides default behavior in case you will not
      // create a specific behavior for a specific shape.
      //for example, just call the unspecific juggler:
      this->Shape::juggle_by(static_cast<Juggler&>(t));
    }
    virtual void juggle_by(TriangleJuggler& t) {
      //provides default behavior in case you will not
      //create a specific behavior for a specific shape.
      //for example, just call the unspecific juggler:
      this->Shape::juggle_by(static_cast<Juggler&>(t));
    }
   //...
};
// Now deriving a class from it
class Square : public Shape {
  void juggle_by(SquareJuggler& s) override{
     //code specific to SquareJuggler and Shape
  }
};
class Triangle : public Shape {
  void juggle_by(TriangleJuggler& t) override{
     //code specific to TriangleJuggler and Shape
  }
};

class ShapeJuggler {
  virtual void juggle(shared_ptr<Shape> s) {
    //by default (if default has sense):
    s->juggle_by(*this);
  }
};
class SquareJuggler: public ShapeJuggler {
public:
  void juggle(shared_ptr<Shape> s) override {
      s->juggle_by(*this);
  }
};
class TriangleJuggler: public ShapeJuggler {
public:
  void juggle(shared_ptr<Shape> s) override {
      s->juggle_by(*this);
  }
};
// Calling the juggle method
void main(void) {
    shared_ptr<Square> square_ptr = (shared_ptr<Square>) new Square();
    SquareJuggler squareJuggler;
    squareJuggler.juggle(square_ptr); 
       //This last call, will perform two virtual calls:
       //   1. SquareJuggler::juggle(shared_ptr<Shape);
       //   2. Square::juggle_by(SquareJuggler&);
}
```

You could also defines your XXXJuggler as final, which will enable some devirtualization optimization.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide this very complete and clear explanation.