# Why can't I use the inherited class when I called abstract class?

Tags: c++, oop, singleton, abstract-class, factory

## **Problem:**

My code is about using abstract class **Shape** and creating 3 shapes **Rectangle**, **Circle**, and **Triangle**. I used a factory and singleton design pattern in the **ShapeFactory** class. When I read the file, I called the method **getInstance()** and pointed to the **createShape** method. After that, I pointed to the derived class and called the setter to set some variables. The problem is it's said that my abstract class doesn't have any setter members.

## **Tries:**

I have tried to create all the setter to the **Shape** class and it worked but it violates object-oriented programming rules so I'm trying to do other ways. I have also tried to search for the errors but it doesn't meet my needs.

## **The error:**

```
oop3.cpp: In member function 'void ShapeFileIO::readFile(std::__cxx11::string, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Shape> >&)':
oop3.cpp:259:28: error: 'using element_type = class Shape' {aka 'class Shape'} has no member named 'setWidth'; did you mean '_width'?
                 rectangle->setWidth(stod(width));
                            ^~~~~~~~
                            _width
oop3.cpp:260:28: error: 'using element_type = class Shape' {aka 'class Shape'} has no member named 'setHeight'; did you mean '_height'?
                 rectangle->setHeight(stod(height));
                            ^~~~~~~~~
                            _height
oop3.cpp:270:25: error: 'using element_type = class Shape' {aka 'class Shape'} has no member named 'setRadius'; did you mean '_radius'?
                 circle->setRadius(stod(radius));
                         ^~~~~~~~~
                         _radius
oop3.cpp:284:27: error: 'using element_type = class Shape' {aka 'class Shape'} has no member named 'setSide1'; did you mean '_side1'?
                 triangle->setSide1(stod(side1));
                           ^~~~~~~~
                           _side1
oop3.cpp:285:27: error: 'using element_type = class Shape' {aka 'class Shape'} has no member named 'setSide2'; did you mean '_side2'?
                 triangle->setSide2(stod(side2));
                           ^~~~~~~~
                           _side2
oop3.cpp:286:27: error: 'using element_type = class Shape' {aka 'class Shape'} has no member named 'setSide3'; did you mean '_side3'?
                 triangle->setSide3(stod(side3));
                           ^~~~~~~~
                           _side3
```

## **My code:**

### This is my code that gets errors:

```cpp
auto rectangle = ShapeFactory::getInstance()->createShape("Rectangle");
                rectangle->setWidth(stod(width));
                rectangle->setHeight(stod(height));

auto circle = ShapeFactory::getInstance()->createShape("Circle");
                circle->setRadius(stod(radius));

auto triangle = ShapeFactory::getInstance()->createShape("Triangle");
                triangle->setSide1(stod(side1));
                triangle->setSide2(stod(side2));
                triangle->setSide3(stod(side3));
```

### This is my factory class:

```cpp
class ShapeFactory {
public:
    map<string, shared_ptr<Shape>> _prototypes;
private:
    inline static shared_ptr<ShapeFactory> _instance = nullptr;
    ShapeFactory() {
        auto rec = make_shared<Rectangle>();
        auto cir = make_shared<Circle>();
        auto tri = make_shared<Triangle>();

        _prototypes.insert({"Rectangle", rec});
        _prototypes.insert({"Circle", cir});
        _prototypes.insert({"Triangle", tri});
    }
public:
    static shared_ptr<ShapeFactory> getInstance() {
        if (_instance == nullptr) {
            auto temp = new ShapeFactory();
            _instance = shared_ptr<ShapeFactory>(temp);
        }
        return _instance;
    }

    shared_ptr<Shape> createShape(string shape) {
        auto it = _prototypes[shape];
        auto result = it->clone();
        return result;
    }
};
```

### This is my abstract class:

```cpp
class Shape {
protected:
    string _shape;

public:
    Shape() { _shape = ""; }
    Shape(string shape) { _shape = shape; }
    virtual ~Shape() {}

public:
    void setShape(string shape) { _shape = shape; }
    virtual string magicWord() = 0;
    virtual shared_ptr<Shape> clone() = 0;
};
```

### This is my ShapeFileIO class:

```cpp
class ShapeFileIO {
public:
    void readFile(string fileName, vector<shared_ptr<Shape>>& shapes) {
        ifstream inFile;
        inFile.open(fileName);
        
        if (!inFile) {
            cout << "Unable to open file";
            exit(1);
        }
        string line, width, height, radius, side1, side2, side3;
        while (!inFile.eof()) {          
            getline(inFile, line);
            stringstream ss(line);
            getline(ss, width, '=');
            getline(ss, width, ',');
            getline(ss, height, '=');
            getline(ss, height);
            if (line.find("Rectangle") != string::npos) {
                auto rectangle = ShapeFactory::getInstance()->createShape("Rectangle");
                rectangle->setWidth(stod(width));
                rectangle->setHeight(stod(height));
                shapes.push_back(rectangle);
            }

            getline(inFile, line);
            stringstream ss2(line);
            getline(ss2, radius, '=');
            getline(ss2, radius);
            if (line.find("Circle") != string::npos) {
                auto circle = ShapeFactory::getInstance()->createShape("Circle");
                circle->setRadius(stod(radius));
                shapes.push_back(circle);
            }

            getline(inFile, line);
            stringstream ss3(line);        
            getline(ss3, side1, '=');
            getline(ss3, side1, ',');
            getline(ss3, side2, '=');
            getline(ss3, side2, ',');
            getline(ss3, side3, '=');
            getline(ss3, side3);
            if (line.find("Triangle") != string::npos) {
                auto triangle = ShapeFactory::getInstance()->createShape("Triangle");
                triangle->setSide1(stod(side1));
                triangle->setSide2(stod(side2));
                triangle->setSide3(stod(side3));
                shapes.push_back(triangle);
            }
        }
        cout << "File read successfully" << endl << endl;
        inFile.close();
    }
};
```

Comment: your shape factory creates shapes and a shape doesnt have the methods you are trying to call

Comment: Perfect example of [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) violation.

Comment: @TedLyngmo you are right.

Comment: Just a note. I usually see the shorthand `auto it` used only in the case of iterators. In your code it is used as a generic variable name. As 463035818_is_not_a_number points out, and as the error message quite clearly states, your `Shape` class doesn't contain the method `setWidth` etc.

Comment: Please include the code of `ShapeFileIO::readFile(std::string, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Shape> >&)`. The error is right there.

Comment: @zkoza I have uploaded, please take a look, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is easy to explain, less easy to correct.
Look at this line:

```
auto rectangle = ShapeFactory::getInstance()->createShape("Rectangle");
```

Here we have this `auto` that's supposed to make life easier, but sometimes it hides the real problems. Namely: what is the type of `rectangle` here? To settle this, let's look at the declaration of `createShape`:

```
shared_ptr<Shape> ShapeFactory::createShape(string shape);
```

So, this function returns `shared_ptr<Shape>`. Thus, your `rectangle` is of type `shared_ptr<Shape>`, too, and in this expression

```
rectangle->setWidth(stod(width));
```

you tell the compiler to access the member  `setWidth` of class `Shape`. The compiler is obliged to protest and refuse to do so, because `Shape` is a base class with no method named `setWidth`.

How to fix this is a different story. The easiest way would be to use some form of the dynamic cast on the pointer returned by `createShape`,

```
auto base_ptr = ShapeFactory::getInstance()->createShape("Rectangle");
auto rectangle = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Rectangle> (base_ptr);
```

One problem with it is that it is ugly and there's danger that you'll need to resort to dynamic casts in several other parts of the program. That would be weird and undesired. I don't use factories etc., you'll need to find the solution that suits your needs yourself.

See also: [c++ Inheritance and shared pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42759612/c-inheritance-and-shared-pointers)

PS. Next time when you ask on SO, please try to provide a [Minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - you would have had a clear, precise answer minutes after posting the question.